# SELinux: command line tool to look security context (like selabel_lookup(3))

Tags: selinux

The `selabel_lookup(3)` library function gives a way to obtain the SELinux security context information for a file - or rather what security label a file is expected to have [1].

Is there a command line utility which looks up security context information for a file from the policy definitions - possibly one that even uses `selabel_lookup(3)` under the covers?

I can sort of use a *reverse* `grep(1)` to search `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts`.  It looks like entries use extended regular expressions (so `egrep` rather than `grep`).  So I'd have to search the keys in `file_contexts` by iterating over them and applying the key to a regex search against my file name.  That could get time consuming.  For instance, Fedora 23 has 5935 lines in `file_contexts`, so that could mean 5935 invocations of grep.  I was hoping for a more efficient solution than that.

[1] `ls -Z` or `secon` gives *current* security context for a file, but that may not be the correct context for that file (as outlined in the SELinux policy definition for the system).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `matchpathcon(8)` (from the `libselinux-utils` package) does the trick:

```
% matchpathcon /tmp
/tmp    system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0
% matchpathcon /tmp/foobar
/tmp/foobar     <<none>>
```

I think that should satisfy my needs [1].

You can use `matchpathcon` to verify existing files' labels:

```
% matchpathcon -V /tmp
/tmp verified
```

Although -V is a little confusing for files that have no policy defined:

```
% matchpathcon -V /tmp/foobar; echo $?
/tmp/foobar has context unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0, should be <<none>>
1
```

I would think a context value of `<<none>>` would match any context successfully instead of being flagged as an error.  The current implementation that I tested (libselinux-utils 2.4.4) flags those cases with a non-zero exit code (as shown above).

[1] My actual need is to look up the proper security context of a file in a mounted chroot image of a removable disk and set it to the proper context based on system defined policy - this will ensure the disk gets the proper security labels before being deployed.  I specifically wanted to look up the security context for `/tmp` in order to apply that context to a custom directory that has `/tmp`-like semantics.  The custom directory is not (yet) defined in a `file_contexts` list.